# WinApi - how to count icons inside file?

Tags: winapi, count, icons

i can not use WinAPI_ExtractIconEx cause i just want to Count the numbers of Icons inside a abritary fileobject. Is there an extra function doing this for me??

Answer (score 3):

Call `EnumResourceNames` or `EnumResourceNamesEx`. You specify a resource type to enumerate. And your callback function is called for each resource of that type.